# CSS multiple parent selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would change the CSS rule for the background to li.li-class if it contain an **h3**.
I have an HTML like this:

```
<div class="div-class">
    <ul>
        <li class="li-class">
            <span itemprop="something">
                <h3>Some title</h3>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the CSS for li background is:

```
.div-class ul li:nth-child(2n+1) {  background: #f4f4f4; }
```

Where is the CSS selector for the li.li-class?

I have look this question [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) and i try the code, but not work in this case.
Thanks all

Comment: Not possible. There's no such thing

Comment: The question you link to explicitly states that the behaviour you desire is not possible, unfortunately. (For posterity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: would you perhaps be creating this html/css with a server side language?  if so, you could test for the h3 contents and add a class to the li.

Comment: Thank you @Serlite , you think this is possible by javascript?

Comment: Absolutely possible by JS! Jake gives a pretty good suggestion in his answer (if you're not adverse to jQuery, of course).

Comment: Thanks @WEBjuju , yes the HTML code is created by php, 
but I do not believe it is possible to give a CSS rule, because I do not know which of the <li> must have the CSS rule. I am wrong?

Comment: @Serlite i like jQuery, :-) but I thought I did not use it to be lighter on the web page. But i think it is a good idea! Thanks!!!

Comment: @kampageddon If this would be the only thing you loaded jQuery for, then maybe it would be a bit much - for a pure JS solution, you can try out [`Node.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, this is not possible using pure CSS.

It would however be very straight forward using the jQuery [.has()](https://api.jquery.com/has/):

```
$("li").has("h3").addClass("yellow");
```

For the HTML:

```
<style>
.yellow{
  background-color:yellow;
}
</style>    
<div class="div-class">
  <ul>
    <li class="li-class">
      <span itemprop="something">
        <h3>Some title</h3>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li class="li-class">
      <span itemprop="something">
        <p>
          Not a header
        </p>
      </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Will look at every `li` element and if it has a descendant `h3` element it will add the yellow class to the `li`.

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/v4o3yqLt/)

You can also make the selector more specific, so it does not select all `li`s but only the ones in a `<div class="div-class">` with something like

```
$("div.div-class").find("li").has("h3").addClass("yellow");
```

Comment: Just a moment... I'm trying this code, I will edit this comment in a moment.

Comment: Exactly @Jake ! Your code has soled my problem. I used this: $("div.div-class").find("li").has("h3").addClass("yellow"); This is the way! Unfortunately my problem is not solvable by CSS. Thanks All for comment, idea and solution!

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating the html via php you have ultimate control:

```
<?php
  $html = '';
  foreach ($rows as &$row) {

    // just figure out if you need the class
    // before making the html - php is power

    if (!empty($row['h3'])) {
      $lih3_class = 'h3-in-li';
    } else {
      $lih3_class = '';
    }

    $html .= '<li class="li-class '.$lih3_class.'">';
    $html .= ''; // put in your li contents as normal
    $html .= '</li>';

  }
  echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: I forgot one important detail: the php code is very complex, so I'd rather not editarlo.Ma I think that this solution will solve my problem!